# Why is my MouseState not correct?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to take mouse input to place towers in a Tower defense game I'm making. Everything works fine except that when I place down the tower it isn't placed where my pointer is. I ran a little test and had the game draw a sprite where it thought my pointer is and it drew it far away from my pointer. This is the code I'm using to get the mouse co-ordinates:

```
mouseState = Mouse.GetState(); //mouseState is of type MouseState

cellX = (int)(mouseState.X / 80);
cellY = (int)(mouseState.Y / 80);

tileX = cellX * 80;
tileY = cellY * 80;
```

And here is the code where the tower uses the co-ords:

```
Tower tower = new Tower(BlueberryBushTexture, new Vector2(tileX, tileY));
```

The only thing I can think of is that I must be using the MouseState coords wrong. Thank YOU!!!

Comment: That math, to me, looks like it's setting `tileX` and `tileY` to the integer portions of the mouse coordinates, since you're dividing then multiplying by 80. What's the difference between "cell" and "tile"? After the first two calculations, don't `cellX` and `cellY` already represent the tile coordinates of where you're clicking?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work it just spawned all my towers in the upper left corner

Comment: I used code from a tutorial from that part and this is what he said

Comment: In the above example if the mouse was at position (77, 114) and we use the above equation to calculate where that is in array space we get the following :

CellX = (int) (77 / 32)

= (int) (2.40625)

= 2

Which is correct, as we can see in the image the point is in the third square along. Now we know what cell the pointer is in we can work out where that cell is in level space by multiplying it by 32 (The the widow of our tiles)

TileX = 2 * 32 = 64

Comment: Yep, you're right. My mistake. Try putting in print statements and see the value of `tileX` and `tileY` when you click; check and see if the values are coming up as what you expect. You may have some broken logic on actually placing the tower.

Comment: I put in a breakpoint, checked the locals, and CellX and CellY were not correct

Comment: They were supposed to be X - 9, and Y - 11 but they actually were X - 6 Y - 4

Comment: And you're sure that your tiles are 80 units square?

Comment: Yes they are 80 pixels

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to verify that the mouse coordinates also make sense with what you expect; this is easier if you have a small window.

Comment: They don't. If I didn't know better I'd say that the Mouse State was messed up

Comment: What happens if you try :`Tower tower = new Tower(BlueberryBushTexture, new Vector2(mouseState.X - 40, mouseState.Y - 40));`

Comment: It's still off plus it doesn't place the towers in the right place

Comment: Does anyone know a better way to take the input and place the tower

Comment: Okay this is weird I can't get onto the discussion board

Comment: @esel and Detinator10, look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing and multiplying, you could simply utilise Modulus!

```
mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

tileX = (int)(mouseState.X - (mouseState.X % 80));
tileY = (int)(mouseState.Y - (mouseState.Y % 80));

/*
This way it will always be highest multiple of 80 lower the the Mouse's position

E.g. mouseState = (243, 712)
tileX = (int)(243 - (243 % 80));
      = (int)(243 - (3));
      = 240;

tileY = (int)(712 - (712 % 80));
      = (int)(712 - (72));
      = 640;

Doing check sum's like this can be really helpful when later modifying 
(Say you make the center of the tile its origin, instead of the top-left corner)
*/
```

And this should help you with your conundrum, and hopefully with your future game projects.

Mona.

Comment: It didn't work. It was still off and I couldn't even place down towers with this. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but i saw it so....
You are dividing by 80 and then multiplying by 80, you can use Math.Floor().
And this doesn't give you a tile index it gives you the mouse position. You need to then figure out what tile this points too and if you have a moving camera you need to also consider where the camera is.